# How can I use inferred generics with a generator function per-yield?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've tried this so far, but TypeScript doesn't pick it up (instead saying that `MyGenerator` requires a type argument):

```
type MyGenerator<T extends unknown> = () => Generator<Promise<T>, void, T>;
const test: MyGenerator = function* () {
    // this variable should end up being typed as a response
    const response = yield fetch("/");
    // this variable should end up being typed as a string
    const text = yield response.text();
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDiEB2EBOBDYB7VAeAKlBAB7DIAmAzlAK5IDWSWA7kgHxQC8UAFAJRcOiFBmx4ACqiwBbAJaUIBNgBooANyyzyq-GwDcAKADGWJJWBQy5gFywEyNJhxcoAMzpHgs0wCpeAgG8DAEgAelDLAAt5dXRUWXQAIwAbaEpIrBpk8iIkHJowKESIWSQAc0twCBz0anQoVAhKMFMFEJMzC0bm1uhuEFkIbLcIYCNIngAiUMm+QzCI4GjqNTiElLSMrJyKWkLi0orQSBq6qHN48oMoG6gO80sSC37B4e6WswgAOjJSfkMAL56IA)

Is there a way I can get the result as stated in the comment? I am aware I can use async/await, I just used this as an example.

Comment: you declared MyGenerator with a genericType, so you need to declare this generic type when you declare a variable const test: MyGenerator<???> otherwise it does not make sense.

Comment: @tlvi38 I'm trying to have TypeScript infer the generic type per-yield, [just like how you can do so with function parameters.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables) I've also made the question title more specific to clear things up.